# CachingFramework.Redis Timeout when using Tags

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, cachingframework.redis

I'm implementing a cache using the tagging mechanism in [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#tagging-mechanism).

My app can read and write to Redis successfully, and I can create tags in Redis (which I can see in Desktop Manager). However I get a timeout exception **only when I attempt to read from the tag store in Redis**:

> System.TimeoutException: 'Timeout performing TYPE :$*tag*$:_HB, inst: 63, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 1, qu: 1, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: LAPTOP-GLFEVSO4, serverEndpoint: 127.0.0.1:6379, keyHashSlot: 14024, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=200,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=200,Max=1000), Local-CPU: 100% (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)'

The calling code is like this:

```html
  var tags = new List<string>();
  if (conditionA == true) { tags.Add("_HB"); }
  if (conditionB == false) { tags.Add("_NHB");}
  var foundKeys = Redis.Cache.GetKeysByTag(tags.ToArray()); //the timeout happens here
```

I've checked that memory usage and CPU are not an issue, and I've increased MinIOThreads in machine.config. I'm out of ideas...  is this a bug in CachingFramework.Redis (or the underlying StackExchange.Redis), or am I doing something wrong?

[* I'm using VS2017/IIS Express, in debug mode, against a local Redis standalone instance on my development machine]

***UPDATE***
The issue only occurs in debug mode in Visual Studio. At runtime, it seems fine. However, it would be nice to be able to debug.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the cachingframework.redis library, but do you connect to a redis cluster or standalone?

Comment: Standalone on local machine. See my update to the question

Comment: CachingFramework.Redis is excellent, by the way... has saved me from writing a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code. ... now if only I could debug on a breakpoint! ;)

Comment: you can clone the [CF.Redis repository](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis.git) and add it as a project to your solution. Current version of the project is VS2015 dotnet v1.0.1.

Comment: You can open a new issue [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/issues/new) and share some code to reproduce the problem so I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @thepirat000 ... I'll add the repo code to my solution, and see what happens.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing Sync and Async calls.